# Count specific month from UTC format using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a count statement of selecting a specific month from yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

```
DateTime
-------------------
2018-01-20 14:31:07
2018-01-20 14:09:07
2018-02-20 12:02:07
2018-02-20 11:31:07
```

My initial code is,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table WHERE DateTime LIKE '%Jan%'
```

My expected result

```
Jan = 2
Feb = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `YEAR()` and `MONTH()`

```
SELECT YEAR(`DateTime`) AS `YEAR`,
       MONTH(`DateTime`) AS `MONTH`,
       COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM tableName
GROUP BY YEAR(`DateTime`),
       MONTH(`DateTime`)
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f11de/1).

Comment: It works fine on the demo, but I'm getting null values

Comment: can you show us your data and a screenshot of your output?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MONTH(DateTime), COUNT(*) AS count FROM table GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: You probably meant `GROUP BY MONTH(DateTime)`.

Comment: @axiac that's a perfectly valid (if a little lazy and opaque) group by clause on most platforms. It's just referring to the column by its index.

Comment: @Thom you are right, [column positions can be used in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html#idm139918184907216), I just forgot about it. On the other hand, MySQL allow using a SELECT expression alias in the `GROUP BY` clause. I think the query is more clear this way: `SELECT MONTH(DateTime) AS mon, COUNT(*) AS count FROM table GROUP BY mon`.